# Do zero divisor pairs in reduced rings always come from two distinct minimal prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a reduced, noetherian $k$-algebra ($k$ a field) with minimal prime ideals $P_1,\ldots,P_r$. If $a \in P_1$, $a \neq 0$.

> Is there $b \in P_i$, $b \neq 0$ with $i \neq 1$ such that $ab = 0$.

When I try to come up with examples in geometry, I always produce coordinate rings of plane affine curves $k[T]/f(T)$ where $T := T_1,\ldots,T_n$ and $f(T) \in k[T]$ is reducible into distinct factors. Then the above should hold.

But I have no clue if this generalizes. If not, I would like to see an example. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this paper [The minimal prime spectrum of a reduced ring](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256046365) as Proposition 1.2. statement 1.

Let $P := P_i$ be a minimal prime of $S$. It follows directly from the fact that $S_{P}$ is the quotient field of $S/P$. For every $a \in P$ we have $a/1 = 0$ in $S_{P}$ and hence by definition there is some $b \notin P$ such that $ab = 0$. Since $S$ was reduced, we deduce that $b \in P_i$ for some $i \neq 1$.